# Picking a few random properties from an Object

Tags: javascript, object, random, properties

If I have a few objects as below:

```
var points = {'p1':{x:1,y:1,z:2}, 'p2':{x:2,y:1,z:4},.....,'p10':{x:3,y:2:z:2}};
var lines = {'l1':{....},'l2':{....},......,'l10'{....}};
var jsonObject = {'info': 'information', 'points': points, 'lines': lines};
```

How do I pick (for example, 3 random points and 3 random lines) from respective objects and update in `jsonObject` such that the new `jsonObject` now contains `{'info': 'information', 'points': pointObj, 'lines': lineObj};` where `pointObj` contains 3 random points from the orighinal `points` object and `lineObj` contains 3 random lines from the original `lines` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As its an Object with keys, you can use Object.keys to get its all keys as an array:

```
var getRandoms = function(source, number) {
  var keys = Object.keys(source) // get all keys as array
      ,len = keys.length;        // keys count

  var result = {};

  // not enough points, so just return all object from source.
  if (len < number) {
    return source;
  }
  var rand, key, count = 0;
  while (count < number) {
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
    key = keys[rand];
    result[key] = source[key];
    // Remove used key
    keys.splice(rand, 1);
    --len;
    ++count;
  }

  return result;
}

jsonObject.points = getRandoms(points, 3);
jsonObject.lines = getRandoms(lines, 3);
```

Comment: The last 2 lines will ruin the original "points" and "lines" objects, right?

Comment: What do you mean `ruin`? do you mean the  `var points;` or the `jsonObject.points`?

Comment: Doing operations like splice on `keys` array won't have any effects on input source.

Comment: Aww, I get it now. So, the original `var points` won't change. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, it just take it as reference, and create new points by randomly point to 3 among source.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `random()` function.

`var randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));`

Now based on the randomNum pick an entry using it's index.

```
var jsonObject = {
    "points" : [],
    "lines" : []   
};
var count = 0;
while(count <3)
{
var randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10))
jsonObject["points"].push(points[randomNum][0]);

randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
jsonObject["lines"].push(lines[randomNum][0]); 
count++;
}
```

Comment: That makes my jsonObject.points to an array, right? is there a method similar to array's ".push()" for object?

Comment: you mean object of objects?

Comment: ```var jsonObject = {
    "points" : {},
    "lines" : {} 
};```
Something like that.

Comment: `var jsonObject = { "points" : { "0" : {x:1, y:2, z:3}, "1" : {x:1,y:2,z:4}..... }, "lines" : {} };` like this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a function which return randomly chosen number between [0-10)

```js
function get3RandomPoint(){
  var temp, arr=[];
   while(arr.length < 3) {
     temp = Math.ceil(Math.random()*10);
     if(arr.indexOf(temp) === -1) {
      arr.push(temp);
     }
    }
  return arr;
 }


var points = {'p1':{x:1,y:1,z:2}, 'p2':{x:2,y:1,z:4},.....,'p10':{x:3,y:2:z:2}};
var lines = {'l1':{....},'l2':{....},......,'l10'{....}};

var randomNums = get3RandomPoint();
var randomPoints = {p1: points["p"+ randomNums[0]], p2: points["p"+ randomNums[1]], p2: points["p"+ randomNums[2]]};

randomNums = get3RandomPoint();
var randomLiness = {l1: points["l"+ randomNums[0]], l2: points["l"+ randomNums[1]], l2: points["l"+ randomNums[2]]};

var jsonObject = {'info': 'information', 'points': randomPoints, 'lines': randomLiness};

console.log(jsonObject);
```